# How to use a different unique identifier of Django ForeignKey field in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following `Model`s:

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Borrow(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

and the following `ModelForm`:

```py
class CreateBorrowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Borrow
        fields = ['book']

    def clean_book(self):
        book = self.cleaned_data['book']
        try:
            return Book.objects.get(id=book, available=True)
        except Book.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Book does not exist or it is unavailable')
```

I would like to have a form that expects the `isbn` field of the `Book` model, instead of `id`. As the `isbn` field is unique, it does make sense. In the `clean_book` method I would need to do a little change to have the following line:

```py
return Book.objects.get(isbn=book, available=True)
```

The problem is that I cannot find an approach to force the form to use a different unique identifier. In my specific case, this is required to avoid brute force enumerating over numerical IDs.

Comment: So I work in a bookstore. Using an ISBN as an unique identifier is not really a great idea at all. Books can have the same ISBN, especially if they're part of a larger series. Many publishers reuse ISBNs (which they shouldn't). Many older books don't even have an ISBN, as the ISO standard for ISBNs was established in 1970. In short: it's a bad idea, don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use a custom field for that, and override the `save()` method instead of the `clean__field()`:

```
class CreateBorrowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    book_isbn = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Borrow
        fields = ['book_isbn']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        book_isbn = self.cleaned_data['book_isbn']
        try:
            book = Book.objects.get(isbn=book_isbn, available=True)
            instance.book = book
        except Book.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError('Book does not exist or it is unavailable')
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance
```